# Fixed positioning a list element on mouse over - jQuery

Tags: jquery, overflow

I want to show overflow area in a list element when the mouse over.

Normally element's height set to 200px and has an overflow area (not showing.).

```
$('#extra_product ul li').live('mouseenter',function(){
    var t = $(this);
    var sHeight = t.height();
    t.css({"height":"auto","z-index":"999"});
    var eHeight = t.height();
    t.height( sHeight ).animate({ height: eHeight });
});
```

This is working but other elements are affecting and moving to next and down. I don't want to affect other elements, just animate to actual height and stay over the below element.

Working demo URL : http://jsfiddle.net/D9P7V/

Comment: can you also specify some of the rendered html code... and css applied to these elements because these bugs or issues generally are related to all of that. it helps debugging when we have markup and css available too.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/D9P7V/ here working demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how i did it, it is not perfect yet you might need some css tweaks of course
the trick i used:

in javascript, clone the element to be shown, and append it to the body, so it cannot influence the other markup anymore, then position it over the element, and show it (animate it, anything you like)

example started from your code:
http://jsfiddle.net/D9P7V/4/

**edit** added solution without cloning

another solution, if you want to leave the markup in, and don't clone,
is setting the LI element on position: relative, and placing the div with extra about content absolute to that LI.

example can be found here:
http://jsfiddle.net/D9P7V/5/

**end edit**

Comment: Your solution is true and really useful. I will use this is i can't find any solution to my script. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you should use position absolute  ( inside a relative div) and then your bottom div wont be affected

Comment: I'm working with li elements for listing. Using div elements just for  designing li element's inside. If i use absolute positioning for li elements, i have to calculate top and left coordinates for each listing element. So there must be another way to do this.

Comment: the idea that Royi Namir shows, is not positioning the LI absolute but the div with extra about items. you need to animate the div not the LI, the LI should always stay the same, it is relative, and you place the div with extra about text absolute within the LI, and then show hide / animate the div.